# How to set the language for the react-i18next `<Trans>` component?

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

Using the basic translation function from i18next you can specify a language in order to display the english and another language side-by-side:

```js
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next'

...

const { t } = useTranslation()

...

`${t('Official Ballot')}/${t('Official Ballot', { lng: 'es' })}` // Official Ballot/Boleta Oficial
```

### However the `<Trans>` component doesn't seem to have a `lng` prop/option… or does it?

(Ignore that there is no additional html markup which is typically used with the `<Trans />` tag. This is a simplified example.)

```js
import { Trans } from 'react-i18next'

...

<Trans i18nkey="Official Ballot" /> // Official Ballot
```

## ⬆ how to set "lng" for this tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trans` component has a `tOptions` prop which get passed to `t` method.

```js
<Trans
  i18nKey={"message"}
  tOptions={{ lng: "de" }} // <--
  components={[<strong>placeholder</strong>]}
/>
```

[A working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-example-cz78s?file=/src/app.js:712-856)